# Query array<string> in hive

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

I am trying to select from an array in Hive and I'm having trouble doing so.

The statement I am trying is as follows:

```
select * from table where ID = 'tennis'
```

ID field is of type array

A sample of array data in the id field would look like `id = ('tennis', 'soccer', 'football')`

Comment: A sample of array data in the id field would look like id = ('tennis', 'soccer', 'football')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_contains` function is probably what you need:

```
select * from table where array_contains(ID,'tennis')
```